# Save page by page in pdf from a pdf file in a specific folder

Tags: vba, pdf, acrobat

I'm trying to save page by page in pdf from a pdf file in a specific folder, I need help in my vba code:

```
    Sub SplitPDF()
    
        Dim PDFPath As String
        Dim PDFDoc As Object
        Dim i As Integer
        
        'Defina o caminho do arquivo PDF
        PDFPath = "C:\Users\Instruções 2061 229 revisão5_revPGM.pdf"
        
        'Crie um objeto PDFDoc
        Set PDFDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        
        'Abra o arquivo PDF
        PDFDoc.Open (PDFPath)
        
        'Itere sobre cada página e salve-a como um arquivo PDF individual
        For i = 0 To PDFDoc.GetNumPages() - 1
            PDFDoc.SaveAs "C:\Users\arquivo_" & i + 1 & ".pdf", 1, i, i
        Next i
        
        'Feche o documento PDF
        PDFDoc.Close
        
    End Sub
```

the following error appears:

> runtime error '-2146959355 (80080005)': This interface is not
> supported

I already activated the reference 'Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library'.

Comment: Do you have Adobe Acrobat installed with a valid Standard or Pro licence?

Comment: I can recommend Coherent PDF for such actions. It is a free commandline tool that doesn't need installation. You can run the commandline from your code.